# KafkaConsumer Java API subscribe() vs assign()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new with Kafka Java API and I am working on consuming records from a particular Kafka topic.

I understand that I can use method `subscribe()` to start polling records from the topic. Kafka also provides method `assign()` if I want to start polling records from selected partitions of the topics.

I want to understand if this is the only difference between the two?

Comment: *Subscribe* makes use of the consumer group; Kafka coordinator sends assignment to a consumer and the partitions of the topics subscribed to, will be distributed to the instances within that group.

*Assign* forces assignment to a list of topics.

Comment: Thanks, @Spara. Got it. ```subscribe()``` gives InvalidGroupIdException if I don't provide a GroupId but ```assign()``` works fine. So every process with ```assign()``` is independent and will receive all the records from topic partition?

Comment: @Spara Your comment implies that assign can not use a consumer group, it can.   The group will not be used for coordination, but for offset tracking.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes `subscribe` need `group.id` because each consumer in a group will dynamically assigned to partitions for list of topics provided in subscribe method and each partition can be consumed by one consumer thread in that group. This is achieved by balancing the partitions between all members in the consumer group so that each partition is assigned to exactly one consumer in the group

`assign` will manually assign a list of partitions to this consumer. and this method does not use the consumer's group management functionality (where no need of `group.id`)

The main difference is `assign(Collection)` will loose the controller over dynamic partition assignment and consumer group coordination

> It is also possible for the consumer to manually assign specific partitions (similar to the older "simple" consumer) using assign(Collection). **In this case, dynamic partition assignment and consumer group coordination will be disabled.**

**subscribe**

```
public void subscribe(java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> topics)
```

The subscribe method Subscribe to the given list of topics to get dynamically assigned partitions. and if the given list of topics is empty, it is treated the same as `unsubscribe().`

> As part of group management, the consumer will keep track of the list of consumers that belong to a particular group and will trigger a rebalance operation if one of the following events trigger -

```
Number of partitions change for any of the subscribed list of topics
Topic is created or deleted
An existing member of the consumer group dies
A new member is added to an existing consumer group via the join API
```

**assign**

```
public void assign(java.util.Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

The assign method manually assign a list of partitions to this consumer. And if the given list of topic partitions is empty, it is treated the same as unsubscribe().

> Manual topic assignment through this method does not use the consumer's group management functionality. As such, there will be no rebalance operation triggered when group membership or cluster and topic metadata change.

Comment: Maybe between the lines, but for those thinking does this mean when using assign() none of the consumer re-balance listeners fire?

Comment: yes while using `assign` you will lose the consumer group coordination @PragmaticProgrammer

Comment: Its worth noting that assign() can  use group.id to store committed offsets.   Its valid to have an assign() consumer with its own dedicated group.id tracking its own offsets without any coordination with other consumers.  There are benefits to this in some scenarios.

Comment: What happens if 2 consumers with assign (with same group id) subscribes to a single partition ? How does auto commit work here. This is not an ideal situation may be, but how do things work in this case?

Comment: Not possible, only one of those consumers will consume from that partition.

Comment: @RyuzakiL In the case of `assign()` what is the correct way to do a seek while starting a consumer?  In the case of `subscribe()` we can make use of `ConsumerRebalanceListener` and `onPartitionsAssigned` we can seek the consumer to the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add some useful information specifically to a consumer without a `group.id`. There is no default to this property (given no framework shenanigans - KafkaClient lib + Java). It's not official, but they're typically called a *free consumer*. a *free consumer* doesn't subscribe to topics, so it's **required to assign**  topic partitions.

As noted above, the concepts of automatic partition assignment, rebalancing, offset persistence, partition exclusivity, consumer heartbeating and failure detection / liveness (all the things that are gifted with a consumer group) are thrown out the window with these *free consumers*. As such, it's up to the client (you) to keep track of any state the app has in relation to kafka, and that includes keeping track of offsets (a Map, for instance). This is because a *free consumer* doesn't commit their offsets to Kafka, and usually your own storage mechanism is used.

Comment: Regarding commits/tracking of offsets:  Scott Carey noticed, that by using group.id it is still possible to have automatic handling of offsets on consumer group level.

Comment: That's correct - the first line in answer says consumers *without* a `group.id`.  Topic distribution feature (to evenly distribute the partitions amongst consumers in the group) isn't possible without it.

Comment: @Nerm If I have 2 `free consumers` assigned to the same topic (let's say with the number of partitions 1) and `auto.offset.reset` set to `earliest`, are both of them guaranteed to get all the messages?

Comment: "Typically called"? They are idle/unassigned. No documentation I've seen says "free consumer"

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes sir. free consumer. I agree that creating a `KafkaConsumer` with `group.id=null` is an idle/unassigned consumer/freeConsumer. Once `freeConsumer.assign(tp)` is invoked, it is no longer an unassigned 'free' consumer. Once this 'free' consumer invokes `.poll()`, it is no longer an idle consumer.----- regarding `no documentation i've seen says 'free consumer'`, Emil Koutanov referenced as such in his book - Effective Kafka

Comment: @tuk If `group.id=null`, and the free consumer has been assigned to the `TopicParition`, one should invoke `.seekToBeginning(tp)` after assignment to guarentee consumer gets all non-expired messages. I have an example that proves this [here](https://github.com/dedovicnermin/stateful_rebalance_client/blob/8428c817265dd0be742645ac88222c6a8b65757c/src/main/java/io/nermdev/kafka/stateful_rebalance_client/rebalance/StatefulRebalanceListener.java#L106) . Under `cfk` directory, sacling the deployment up/down `x` # of times will not break guarantee.