# Is it influential when use assign instead of subscribe in kafka consumer that use the same group_id?

Tags: apache-kafka

When I use `assign` command to consume messages from kafka with two consumers which use the same group_id, will there be any influence to each consumer?

If another consumer use the same group_id with `subscribe` command, will there be any influence to the above consumer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KafkaConsumer Java API subscribe() vs assign()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938125/kafkaconsumer-java-api-subscribe-vs-assign)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, mixing assign (manual partition assignment) and subscribe (dynamic partition assignment) isn't possible, but it's not clear what the problems are exactly or how it will fail.

Two consumers with same group_id work independently, but it can cause commit offset conflicts.

See **Manual Partition Assignment** in [api docs](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

> Each consumer acts independently even if it shares a groupId with
> another consumer. To avoid offset commit conflicts, you should usually
> ensure that the groupId is unique for each consumer instance. Note
> that it isn't possible to mix manual partition assignment (i.e. using
> assign) with dynamic partition assignment through topic subscription
> (i.e. using subscribe).

Comment: I mean two consumer, one use assign, another use subscribe

Comment: Problem is the common `group_id`. Using `assign` basically means that app takes responsibility for partition assignment for a given `group_id` and topic. There's no way to share that responsibility with the Kafka Broker. Also if you think about it, the consumers would have to share information about the messages they've processed to avoid missing messages or getting duplicates. This is possible only if all consumers within `group_id` are `assigned` and you manually also manage offset commits. Can you tell bit more about the problem you're solving? There could be other ways to approach it.