# When Kafka consumer don't use subscribe method, do it check session.timeout.ms or max.pool.interval.ms?

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

this is consumer code with not using subscribe method.

```kotlin
val consumer = KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties)
val topics = listOf(TopicPartition("TEST", 1)

consumer.assgin(topics)

try {
    do {
        val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
        records.forEach {
            println("result : $it")
        }
    } while (!records.isEmpty)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println(e.message)
} finally {
    consumer.close()
}
```

do it check session.timeout.ms, max.pool.interval.ms or hearbeat.interval.ms?
i think if kafka consumer don't use subscribe method, it don't check.

Answer (score 1):

Both `subscribe()` and `assign()` will check for session.timeout.ms,max.pool.interval.ms and other properties that you specify during consumer creation.

Difference between `subscribe()` and `assign()` is that when using

> subscribe() uses `group-id` in the consumer properties and helps in dynamic partition assignment and consumer group coordination

> assign will manually assign a list of partitions to this consumer. and this method does not use the consumer's group management functionality (where no need of `group.id`)

More information here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938125/kafkaconsumer-java-api-subscribe-vs-assign#:~:text=Subscribe%20makes%20use%20of%20the,to%20a%20list%20of%20topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938125/kafkaconsumer-java-api-subscribe-vs-assign#:%7E:text=Subscribe%20makes%20use%20of%20the,to%20a%20list%20of%20topics).