# How do free consumers behave when subscribed to the same topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

*Free Consumers* as discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69776399/785523) are consumers without a `group.id`. They do not subscribe to the topic but topic partitions are **assigned** to them.

Can someone let me know how the *free consumers* behave when they are assigned the same topic partition (`auto.offset.reset` set to `earliest`). Are all the free consumers expected to get all the messages till they are restarted?

- Kafka Client Version - 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for multiple consumers to be assigned to the same partition in a group.

Only when a group rebalances, for any reason, will partitions be reassigned and may be consumed by previously *idle consumers*.

Comment: But I am observing the behaviour different. I have two consumers with no `group.id` and `client.id` set and if I use `assign()` to assign same topic partitions (as described in the linked answer in the question) then I am observing both the consumers are receiving all the messages from the topic. The topic I used for my testing has only 1 partition and the same is **assigned** to both the consumers.

Comment: I see. Yes. Assigned consumers do not use consumer groups. Therefore, you must manually store your offsets somewhere external from Kafka since they wouldn't be stored in consumer offsets topic. I misunderstood the title of your post that said subscribed... So, then I'm not sure about auto.offset.reset ; each consumer manages its own commits and storage. I personally find using assign API is a Kafka anti pattern